# What is .Net Framework 4 extended?

Tags: .net-4.0

For testing purposes, I installed .Net Framework 4 Client Profile.  My tests ended and I was to uninstall it, in order to install .Net Framework 4 full. The uninstaller told me to uninstall .Net Framework 4 extended first.

I've already found it and uninstalled, but the question remains: What is .Net Framework 4 extended?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between Microsoft .NET 4.0 full Framework and Client Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/differences-between-microsoft-net-4-0-full-framework-and-client-profile)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's the part of the .NET Framework that isn't contained within the Client Profile. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) for more info; specifically:

> The .NET Framework is made up of the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile and .NET Framework 4 Extended components that exist separately in Programs and Features.

Answer (score 30):

Got this from Bing. Seems Microsoft has removed some features from the core framework and added it to a separate optional(?) framework component.

To quote from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx)

> The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile
>   does not include the following
>   features. You must install the .NET
>   Framework 4 to use these features in
>   your application:
>
> ```
> * ASP.NET
> * Advanced Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) functionality
> * .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle
> * MSBuild for compiling
> ```

Comment: @ bintechie:  thank you for reading "between the lines"; the article you quote fails (not your fault) to explicitly identify "Microsoft .NET 4 Extended".  The support link(a) from "Control Panel::Add/Remove Programs" is equally useless.  Good catch!  (a) http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/5/7/B57D25A2-B3FD-4668-91B9-DB43B6BD910D/NETFx4RTM.htm