# what's the difference in vs2010 of the target framework: .net framework 4.0 and .net framework 4.0 client profile?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

when right click the property of the project in vs2010, what's the difference of the target framework with or without client profile?
thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Client Profile vs Full](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562076/client-profile-vs-full)

Answer (score 1):

The client profile is a subset of the complete .NET 4 framework, aimed at client side applications. It allows users to have a smaller download and install, leaving out the bits they wouldn't normally use.

However depending upon your application, and which bits of the framework you want to use, you may need the complete version and not the client. For example if you want to access the Membership provider stuff from a WinForms app you'll need the full and not client.

See this for more info:

[Differences between Microsoft .NET 4.0 full Framework and Client Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/difference-between-net4-client-profile-and-full-framework-download)