# How do I deploy a .Net 4.0 full application to an environment that is just .Net 4.0 Client?

Tags: .net-4.0

So we have developed an application that uses the .net 4.0 full(extended) libraries. Our workstations only have .Net 4.0 client on them. Our applications and infrastructure teams are wary about having us deploy .Net 4.0 full to all the workstations and wants to take some time to discuss and test.

Is there some way to deploy the extra .Net Extended dlls with our application so we can go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot supplement with just the dlls. All you can do is update to the full profile or find the features in your app that require the full profile and re-write them to avoid that requirement.

There's actually not that much difference between the two profiles. See the answers to this question for a more complete explanation:

> [Client Profile vs Full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562076/client-profile-vs-full/)

That means that you may have an easier time than you think either re-writing the app to avoid the features, or convincing your staff to update the profile deployed to the workstations. It's likely just some advanced WCF features or a type provided with ASP.Net (like HttpUtility) that you're missing.