# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010/2012 can't see latest .NET Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio, frameworks, ide

I've got a stupid problem, which just couldn't get solved in any obvious way. The point is, that both my good old MSVS 2010 and latest MSVS 2012 "can't see" .NET Frameworks of version 4 or 4.5. These libraries are supposed to be automatically installed with the Visual Studio, so that it would use relevant C# (and not only) features any time.

But I've tried reinstalling the IDE several times - no, only 2,3 and 3.5 framework versions are available when trying to create a new project. Nor any externally created project for latest .NET versions can be opened. Reinstalling IDE on different hard drives, manual framework reinstalling and so on didn't bring success. IDE's are Ultimate Edition both.

I badly wish to solve the problem without attempting to reinstall my windows 7 home basic. Could anyone, please, give me some good piece of advice about it?

P.S. [Almost similar problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/4ac31087-5557-4e60-ba60-98086d523fdb)

Comment: What kind of project are you creating?

Comment: Why don't you download the framework from the MS website and try manually installing them?

Comment: No kinds of projects, which require 4 o 4.5 versions are available. Like latest ASP MVC's for web. Even a simple WPF application can't get targeted for the 4th FW.

Comment: The fact is that there is a similar question about somewhere here on stackoverflow, a guy there discovered, that his Studio started showing error like "Project targets different FW" and a had something like that before, but his solution doesn't help me - full reinstall and reset to defaults haven't helped yet.

Comment: I've tried to download and install FW manually, had to remove it from programs first, but it didn't help. MSVS "doesn't see" it(( 
P.S. Sorry for multi-commenting, haven't got used to the UI yet.
[HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636618/visual-studio-2010-error-project-target-framework-not-installed-when-opening) - what i found here, didn't help.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?  It sounds like you've done a lot of things to fix the problem, and it may be that your system is now horribly corrupted from all the things you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the .NET 4 Multitargeting Pack:

[Multi-Targeting Pack for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.2 (KB2544526)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27758)

[Multi-Targeting Pack for Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.3 (KB2600213)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29052)

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078164/dotnet-framework-4-missing-from-visual-studio-2010