# Visual Studio 2010 does not detect .NET framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

After installing Visual Studio 2010 (multiple times), the IDE refuses to detect .NET framework 4.0 ([it shows 3.5 and below only](http://puu.sh/98ff9/0cb1677837.png)). I have confirmed that the framework and the multi-targeting pack are, in fact, [installed.](http://puu.sh/98ooS/506bf39bc4.png)
I've tried repairing the VS install, but to no avail— it tells me that it the install has failed because it didn't attempt to install the multi-targeting pack.
Any help would be appreciated as this has been a thorn in my side for about half a week now.
Edit: I am running `Windows 8.1`

Comment: Did you also install SP1?

Comment: I won't say it's a duplicate, but have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12788639/1043380)?

Comment: What OS are you running VS under?

Comment: There are more suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3078164/534109

Comment: Yeah, I've installed the multi-targeting pack.
I'm running on win8.1, would that have any impact?

Comment: Also, this is a fresh install, so I haven't moved drives. I doubt there're any registry corruptions, but I'll check. Last time I came across that post, I tried the verification tool, which seemed to return positive for every version of .NET I checked.

Comment: I won't guarantee that Win8 is the problem, but I have had some issues running VS2010 and VS2012 on Win8 and Win8.1

Comment: If you use the WebPI to install SP1, it should detect dependencies you're missing, if any. Haven't tried installing 2010 on 8.1, though. I would suggest editing your question to note the OS you're using.

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me that my install didn't come with SP1, so I'm installing that now, we'll see if it fixes things.

Comment: @HotelCalifornia because you need to have the latest Visual Studio Service pack to run on Windows 8

Comment: @MarkHall is that a general service pack for all forms of VS? Or is it specific to VS2010 (i.e. VS2010 SP1)?

Comment: @HotelCalifornia Specific to VS2010.

Comment: @MarkHall yeah, downloading/installing that now (^^)

Comment: @HotelCalifornia Also see this GDR Release for VS2010 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182/en-us

Comment: After installing SP1 and the Windows 8 GDR for VS2010, the problem persists

Comment: are you installing .net framework 4.5 or 4.0? .. as I find in this wiki is that vs2010 only suports 4.0 but not 4.5, and the screenshot you showed mentions that you are installing 4.5 not 4.0 (even though the dlls are the same, have you tried only 4.0). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio why don't you use 2012 or 2013 version?

Comment: To the people voting to close because Visual studio isn't a tool used primarily for programming, if it isn't I don't know what is.

Comment: @Mahmud I'm using VS2010 becuase of its compatibility with XNA, which a friend and I are using for a project.

Comment: @MarkHall If Visual Studio isn't used for programming, I've been doing something wrong all these years.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the .net v4 redistributable package or the development package? Try this link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9831986

Edit:

There are 2 more things you could try:

1) This solution from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3dede142-82ce-430c-bbe6-d824f0fb94a4/visual-studio-does-not-detect-net-framework-4?forum=netfxsetup

> Downloading and starting "Windows Phone Developer Tools" ... after the
>   first installation process is finished (.net4 Multi-Targeting...) i
>   stopped the installation process and then restarted VS2010 and ... it
>   found the .net4 Framework. (Yes, i tried to uninstall/reinstall all
>   frameworks and vs2010 several times, but nothing else worked here.
>   Win7/64bit)

2) Create a new user account and test it with that.

Comment: After running that: http://puu.sh/98zpi/56bf409b66.png

Comment: I'd forgotten: I already have the WP dev tools (for 7.0, 7.1, and 8.0)

Comment: Finally, after trying to repair from another account, I get the same error as I did initially: http://puu.sh/99AoV/c7ad18870b.png

Comment: Sounds like Windows re-install is your best bet.

Comment: That would not be fun.. I might just have to stick with writing code in Sublime Text and putting on our repo.

Comment: So my only solution aside from reinstalling windows is to convince my partner to use monogame instead of xna. Thanks for all the answers!