# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 .NET Framework not existing?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm getting an error from Visual C++ 2010 that tells me the .NET Framework version 4.0 is not installed on my computer. I have the v4.0.30319 version. It did work until Windows decided to update the .NET framework and my SDK!

This is the message i get:

> The Visual C++-Project "..." uses ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0", which is not installed on this computer. You have to install this framework in order to open this project or to create a new one.

Then it asks me if I want to go to the download page and download the matching version there ot if I want to keep the project unloaded.
I tried installing the 4 and the 4.0.3 version. Nothing did work.
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/hh487282.aspx)

I'm working with Win XP SP3.

Comment: This is pretty unanswerable.  Looks like that update didn't go well.  Restoring your machine back to the restore point before that update would be a logical next step.

Comment: Nothing I haven't noticed ;)  The other huge problem about using a restore point is that this update happened like a month ago and i noticed this only a few days ago. I have installed like a billion other programs in this time. So this is not an option!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2010 error: "Project Target Framework Not Installed" when opening a .NET 4.0 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636618/visual-studio-2010-error-project-target-framework-not-installed-when-opening)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solved it!
I "just" had to completely uninstall the .NET-Framework 4 and VC from my computer and the reinstall it!