# Which version of .net 4.0 should be used for Windows Service (4.0 full or client profile)

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, windows-services, .net-client-profile

With reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/difference-between-net4-client-profile-and-full-framework-download), I would like to know which version (.net 4.0 client profile or full version) should be used for Windows service application and why?

Comment: I can't remember the exact issue I had with using the client, but you want full version.  I'll try to find why.

Comment: @Stefan H: If you can recollect the issue you had with client profile, it would be great help for me. I'll be developing a windows service application which will do multi threading for importing data from various external sources. I dont want to pull down my server because of framework issues.

Comment: The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile does not include the following features. You must install the .NET Framework 4 to use these features in your application:

ASP.NET

Advanced Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) functionality

.NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle

MSBuild for compiling

Comment: @Stefan H: Even I read those points just now http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx. I think I dont require any of those extra features of full version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The project templates for Windows Services target the client profile by default so the choice simply comes down to 2 aspects:

a) What framework features does your service need - is everything you need available in the client profile or are you going to be using features that are only in the full framework?

b) Does the size of you installation package matter?  E.g. If you're package is downloaded and bandwidth is a cost for you then keeping your install package small is clearly a benefit. If this is an internally used service then the size of the install package is likely to be less of an issue.

Comment: +1 for the finding, by default windows service is having .net 4.0 client profile. I got this question because I could not categorise the windows service into client application or web application. But your answer gave a way to me.