# Framework 4 & Framework 4 Client Profile: What is the difference?

Tags: c#, frameworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between .Net4 Client Profile and Full Framework download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/difference-between-net4-client-profile-and-full-framework-download)

I am writing a Windows Service using VS2010 & C#. The default Target Framework is Framework4 Client Profile.

1. What is the difference between the two?
2. Does the choice impact on the deployment of the service?

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From MSDN - [.NET Framework Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx):

> The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is a subset of the .NET Framework 4 that is optimized for client applications.

And:

> This enables faster deployment and a smaller install package for applications that target the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

For a windows service, I would go with the full framework.

Comment: Oded: Thank you. A response such as this is infinitely more valuable than the effort by Jani, Roddy, Donal Fellows, Femaref, Gilles & others; in fact, I'd say the response from the latter group is worse than useless it is counter productive: it ought to be disallowed unless 'exact' no longer means 'exact'.