# Reference to System.data.entity.design.dll not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm working with a new Entity Framework repository and need **System.data.entity.design.dll** for using the `PluralizationService`. Now when I go to add reference, it wont show up in the ".Net" tab. Also if I go to:  **..\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0** and add the dll from there it won't fix my namespace using and will only create a yellow icon at the dll in the reference folder.

Does anyone know how I can fix this, or even where to download the dll again?

Comment: what kind of application are you creating? .NET framework version and so on? are you on x32 or x64 machine? In general I don't think you should reference the design dll of the EF.

Comment: Windows 7, 64x visual studio 2, EF 4, .net Framework 4.1

Comment: @Juilian, when you hover you mouse over the yellow reference, what does it say?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the target framework of your application from **.NET Framework 4 Client Profile** to **.NET Framework 4**.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! What did I actually change now?

Comment: The Client Profile is a subset of the full framework. You can read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/difference-between-net4-client-profile-and-full-framework-download)