# System.Web assembly is not found on .net 4.0 version

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, system.web

I updated .NET from `3.5` to `4.0` version, but after updating the assembly `System.Web` doesn't work any more.

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning 1 Could not resolve assembly "System.Web". The assembly is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.

Using the `3.5` version it works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Target the full version, not the client version.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change the project from ClientProfile to full .NET 4.0

> The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is a subset of the .NET Framework
>   4 that is optimized for client applications. It provides functionality
>   for most client applications, including Windows Presentation
>   Foundation (WPF), Windows Forms, Windows Communication Foundation
>   (WCF), and ClickOnce features. This enables faster deployment and a
>   smaller install package for applications that target the .NET
>   Framework 4 Client Profile.

See [Differences between Microsoft .NET 4.0 full Framework and Client Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/difference-between-net4-client-profile-and-full-framework-download/2786831#2786831)

Answer (score 15):

I think you have `.NET 4.0 Client profile` selected for target framework. Just switch to `.Net 4.0`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You're targetting the .net 4.0 Client Profile, which is a .net "lite" for desktop users. Switch to full .net 4.0 to get at System.Web

Project Properties -> Application tab -> Target Framework

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the "Target Framework" to be ".NET Framework 4" instead of ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile".