# White UI Automation C# loading White.Core assembly fails

Tags: c#, ui-automation, white-framework

I tried to get a simple example running to start the Windows calculator and do some things:

[White: An UI Automation Tool for Windows Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/289028/White-An-UI-Automation-tool-for-windows-applicatio)

Saldy above link is old so I adapted the code from another example:

[The White Windows UI automation getting started tutorial for testers](http://www.tellingmachine.com/post/The-White-Windows-UI-automation-getting-started-tutorial-for-testers.aspx)

My simple code now looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using White.Core;
using White.Core.UIItems;
using White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems;
using White.Core.UIItems.WindowStripControls;
using White.Core.UIItems.MenuItems;
using White.Core.UIItems.TreeItems;
using White.Core.UIItems.Finders;

namespace TestWhiteCalculator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application manager = Application.Launch(@"C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe");

            Window mainWindow = manager.GetWindow("Rechner");
        }
    }
}
```

I also added the `WhiteCore.dll` reference.

I still get an error:

> Warning: The referenced assembly "White.Core" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.

So there is something wrong with loading `White.Core` because of missing `System.Web` reference.

Any ideas? Is this a problem with my .NET installation?

---

Found a solution:

[System.Web assembly is not found on .net 4.0 version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7694380/146622)

You have to change your .NET framework profile from .NET 4.0 Client to .Net 4.0 (full).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add a reference to `System.Web.dll` to your project's references. If you cannot find it, then you might have to [select a different framework profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981204/net-framework-4-client-profile-system-web-dll).

Comment: jep the framework was the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694380/system-web-assembly-is-not-found-on-net-4-0-version