# Why should someone use the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile?

Tags: .net

Are there any good reasons to use .NET Framework 4 [Client Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_3.5_SP1_Client_Profile) instead of the *full version*?

I mean, real-life reasons. I am creating a .NET application, and since it's quite easy to create an installer that will install the .NET framework on a client machine, why bother using the Client Profile?

Comment: Arguably, the fact that Microsoft has discontinued the client profile for .NET 4.5 suggests that the benefits of faster deployment and a smaller install package are marginal at best.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) answers this:

> The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is a subset of the .NET Framework
>   4 that is optimized for client applications. It provides functionality
>   for most client applications, including Windows Presentation
>   Foundation (WPF), Windows Forms, Windows Communication Foundation
>   (WCF), and ClickOnce features. This enables faster deployment and a
>   smaller install package for applications that target the .NET
>   Framework 4 Client Profile.

A smaller install package could be a bonus, especially if you're targeting non-traditional devices like tablets with less storage space.  It's also a shorter download time if the Framework needs to be installed.

Comment: As of .Net 4.5 client profile will no longer be available since they were able to shrink the size of the .net framework redistributable

Comment: Does this imply restrictions on dependent components to be also targeted to client profile framework?

Comment: @ChrisKlepeis See also MS Doc of 2017: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/client-profile . Client Profile is discontinued, however, if 4.5 is installed, the Client Profile is automatically updated to the full 4.5. Confusing, but also a non-problem.

Answer (score 8):

Applications that target the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile typically improve the deployment experience by having smaller download sizes and quicker install times. An application that targets the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile has a smaller redistribution package that installs the minimum set of client assemblies on the user's computer, without requiring the full version of the .NET Framework 4 to be present.

Answer (score 3):

A good answer can be found in Stack Overflow question *[Differences between Microsoft .NET 4.0 full Framework and Client Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228)*. Basically, only use the full framework if you know you need to. Normal client applications should only need the client framework.

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons:

- The client profile has been available as a recommended update on Windows Update since Vista (ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982670), so chances are you don't need to install it at all on your target machines
- being a separate profile it will be updated separately (so clients will not need to update as much, if a security patch for a server-only feature is released)