# Can .NET 4 applications use libraries targeted at .NET 4 Client Profile?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-client-profile

I don't know of any reason why this wouldn't be possible, but I'd like to make sure there aren't any potential pitfalls or gotchas here.

Can a .NET 4 application depend on a class library that's targeted at .NET 4 Client Profile?  Are there any potential problems that could arise?

Comment: Useful reading (with more MSDN links): [Difference between .NET 4 Client Profile and Full Framework download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/difference-between-net-4-client-profile-and-full-framework-download)

Comment: Related: [VS2010 - Getting “type or namespace name could not be found” but everything seems ok?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3304899/109702)

Comment: @slugster: Those comments on your answer... o_O

Comment: @Bolt - yeah, I snorted my coffee when I first saw them :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The client profile [is a subset of the full .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx). Thus everything in the client profile is included in the full framework, so whether it's a client or web application you're building, you shouldn't run into any problems.

Comment: If you or your users *do* run into any problems, I wouldn't rule out a bad .NET Framework installation.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had any issues targeting a .NET 4.0 Client Profile library from a .NET 4.0 web app.

Answer (score 0):

the client profile doesn't include "server" type libraries. most notable is the asp.net framework.  so a dll targeting the client profile can run on full .net 4.0 but a dll targeting .net 4.0 cannot run on a computer only containing the client profile.