# When is the right time to use .NET Framework 4 rather than .NET Framework 4 Client Profile?

Tags: .net, .net-client-profile

Perhaps the issue here is that I don't fully understand the differences between the Client Profile of .NET 4 and the (regular?) version of .NET 4...

When I begin a new project in Visual Studio 2010, it defaults to a target framework of .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.  Occasionaly, when using third party library's I will get compile erros if my project is setup for .NET Framework 4 Client Profile - switching to .NET Framework 4 fixes the issue.

I have always just dealt with this but today I decided to ask the question and figure when to use one over the other, and why there are two versions of the framework.

**EDIT:** If I target .NET 4, should I be concerned that a normal desktop user won't be getting that Framework over Windows Update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concerning your edit: take a look here: [.Net Framework 4 Full and Net Framework 4 Client Profile Targeting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10027301/114029)

This post by [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/) shows you what's in and what's out of the Client Profile:

[Towards a Smaller .NET 4 - Details on the Client Profile and Downloading .NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TowardsASmallerNET4DetailsOnTheClientProfileAndDownloadingNET.aspx)

- Supported on all OS that Full is
- Supported for x86 & x64
- Client Profile is *the* framework that will be available on Windows Update for desktops
- Supported in all aspect of VS (e.g. targeting, deployment project, etc)
- Is the default target in almost all VS10 Client Project Templates (Winforms, WPF, VSTO, etc)

This is the funny part:

> The general idea is that they avoid installing things you don't need on a
>   client machine. That means they won't install ASP.NET on your Mom's
>   computer just because she wants a game. Also, the .NET 4 Client
>   profile is a proper subset of the .NET 4 "Full" Framework.

Here's a more detailed post: [What’s new in .NET Framework 4 Client Profile RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-rtm.aspx)

> **When to use NET4 Client Profile and when to use NET4 Full Framework?**
>   *NET4 Client Profile:*
>   Always target NET4 Client Profile for all your client desktop applications (including Windows Forms and WPF apps).
>
> *NET4 Full framework:*
>   Target NET4 Full only if the features or assemblies that your app need are not included in the Client Profile. This includes:
>
> - If you are building Server apps. Such as:
>           o ASP.Net apps
>           o Server-side ASMX based web services
> - If you use legacy client scenarios. Such as:
>           o Use System.Data.OracleClient.dll which is deprecated in NET4 and not included in the Client Profile.
>           o Use legacy Windows Workflow Foundation 3.0 or 3.5 (WF3.0 , WF3.5)
> - If you targeting developer scenarios and need tool such as MSBuild or need access to design assemblies such as System.Design.dll

---

It's worth mentioning that starting with `.NET 4.5` there's no more a `Client Profile`. It's been discontinued: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx (link provided by [CodingWithSpike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28278/codingwithspike))

Comment: +1 because I was in the middle of posting this same link when you beat me to it :)

Comment: For questions like this we can be sure that Scott Hanselman got us covered... :)