# Add project as reference to another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have two projects in the same solution.
One is an ASP.NET MVC 2 Empty Web Application, 
the other is a Console Application.

In the first project i create a database with EF and a class to access the database.
What I want to do is add the first project as a reference to the console app project so i can use this class

I included it as a reference already it appears at the References, and after is include a using directive at the top of my console app i can even use code assistance. But when i compile i always get the error:

The type or namespace name 'DBModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can i compile my projects?

Sincerely,

Zoli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description, if I'm getting it right,

That's often the case `when you have different target .NET framework` (Project properties, Application, Target Framework) - i.e. one is e.g. .NET 4.0 Client Profile - and the lib you're referencing is just .NET 4.0.

Comment: This was my problem too: thanks! But... what's the difference between vanilla .NET 4.0 and the Client Profile version?

Comment: my pleasure ;) - Here is a good link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/difference-between-net-4-client-profile-and-full-framework-download

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that you're missing a reference to the Entity Framework in your Console application.

See this post for more info: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=617 (just below the middle, step 3).