# Difference between .NET Framework and .NET Framework Client Profile

Tags: .net, version, .net-framework-version

I was reading about `Visual` `abstract class` in the following *msdn* link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx

I found two similar sounding phrases **.NET Framework** and **.NET Framework Client Profile** under "Version Information" heading.

Can you please tell the differences between them?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between Microsoft .NET 4.0 full Framework and Client Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/differences-between-microsoft-net-4-0-full-framework-and-client-profile)

Answer (score 0):

.NET framework 4 Client Profile is a smaller and indeed faster installer when compared to .NET framework 4. .NET framework 4 Client Profile is used to reduce the deployment failures in the framework. .NET framework 4 Client Profile is a redistribution package of smaller size and it installs minimal set of client assemblies.

.NET framework 4 Client Profile is used to create client desktop applications including applications based on Windows Forms and Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications. .NET framework 4 complete installation is required instead of .NET framework 4 Client Profile if the application requires features that are not provided in the .NET framework 4 Client Profile. .NET framework 4 Client Profile is not suitable for the scenarios illustrated below:

Building of server applications like ASP.NET applications and web services based on server side ASMX.
Using legacy client scenarios such as legacy WWF version 3.0 or 3.5.
Using developer scenarios that need MSBuild tools or designer assemblies.
For the above scenarios, .NET framework 4 has to be used instead of .NET framework 4 Client Profile.