# Crystal report for visual studio 2010 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Crystal report for visual studio 2010 (C#):

I've installed the following files:
Crystal Reports 2010 Support Pack 13.0.5
SAP Crystal Reports 13.0 for Visual Studio 2010
SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4 (64-bit)

Add crystal report item and set information.
But the report gives the following error:

The picture is below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The warning text says you are using the client profile.  The Crystal engine relies on System.Web and cannot resolve it.

[Change your project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from the client profile to instead use the full .NET 4.0 profile.  [See this post about profile differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/differences-between-microsoft-net-4-0-full-framework-and-client-profile/2786831#2786831).