# JSON.NET on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c#, .net, json, ubuntu, mono

I'm trying to start using JSON.NET for Mono on Linux and MonoDevelop. I found the packages in the repository, so I installed them using `sudo apt-get install libnewtonsoft-json-cil-dev libnewtonsoft-json-cil monodoc-newtonsoft-json-manual`

I have the following code to test if the installation worked:

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace jsontest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();

            Car my_car = new Car ();
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (my_car);

            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();
        }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public string make;
        public string model;

        public Car()
        {
            make = "ford";
            model = "jalopy";
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the program it gives me the following error: `The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

Why can't MonoDevelop find the library I installed?

Comment: This may or may not be applicable, but on Windows I sometimes see this error if you try to compile a project setup with the 4.0/4.5 Client Profile instead of the Full Profile.

Comment: I haven't seen anything about different profiles so far when looking online. Where can I read up on that?

Comment: [Differences between Microsoft .NET 4.0 full Framework and Client Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/differences-between-microsoft-net-4-0-full-framework-and-client-profile) and [the type or namespace name could not be found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764978/the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After installing it via apt-get,

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/libnewtonsoft-json5.0-cil/filelist

This dll is available in Mono GAC, which you should be able to access in MonoDevelop by adding a new reference. **This reference must be added manually**, or you get the error message.

This is not something "unexpected", as even in Visual Studio if you don't get the references right, the same error message is expected.