# C#/.NET framework availability on various Windows versions or CPUs

Tags: c#, .net, compatibility

I made a Windows Form application targeting .Net 2.0 and x86. Everything runs smooth on my pc but I want to be sure that my app is fully compatible with Windows XP and above. How can I do that?

Is there something else I can do to increase its compatibility? Is downgrading the .NET framwork helpful? Is there any tool to test the compatibility of my .NET app?

I tested my app on an old Windows XP machine and I got an error 0x000013 or something.

Comment: windows xp doesn't by default shipped with .net framework. But you can distribute .net with your application http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx. Also if user doesn't have installed .net in their system, your app will automatically detect it and it will redirect user to download page of .net. And third, you can use .net client profile (use for .net <= 4 version) to distribute .net with your app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if suitable .NET Framework is installed on the PC you want to run your application.
Simply install it if there is none installed yet.
Windows 7 came with .NET Framework(v 3.5 "[full profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/differences-between-microsoft-net-4-0-full-framework-and-client-profile)") preinstalled, Windows XP did not. You can publish your applications and the installation script will check the compatibility for you.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that you can install up to .NET 4.0 on a XP machine. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851 It should be backward compatible with .NET 2.0 application but there's not a reason to not switch to 4.0.