# Will an application targeted for .NET 4.0 work on a system with .NET 4.0 client profile version

Tags: c#

Client on their `WinSerevr 2003 R2 server` has `.NET 4.0 Client Profile` as in this screen shot they sent me:

[image]

I am using VS 2012 Professional and have `Targeted .NET 4.0` ..not

```
4.0 Client Profile
```

Will that be a problem? Should I instead compile to Client Profile one?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/differences-between-microsoft-net-4-0-full-framework-and-client-profile

Comment: It could be a problem if you are using features that aren't supported in client profile. If you intend to support Client Profile installations, you should build to Client Profile... that way you can be sure that you're not accidentally referencing stuff that isn't included in CP. If it won't build, then you have a new problem to consider.

Comment: *Client Profile* is simply a cut version of full framework. Everything what is included will works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends if your application is using features not included in the client profile.

you can see a full list of the assemblies included in the client profile, and a whole host of other information, here: [What’s new in .NET Framework 4 Client Profile RTM](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-rtm.aspx)

Comment: Ok thanks, One last thing to confirm: Do you mean if they are on client profile and I compile to 4.0 Full version, they won't be able to even run the application ? OR do you mean IF my code is using something that is MISSING in Client Profile version, then they won't be able to run it? Thank for info

Comment: The latter - if you're using something in your app that isn't in the profile then it won't run. you're best, like Patrick says, to try and compile under the client profile - if it won't build, you have problems.

Comment: Well I tried to compile all my stuff to Client Profile, one of them that is a core DLL I haven't written it failed, my own program still compiled to Client Profile fine, but my program is referencing that DLL too. So Problems?

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to compile for `Client Profile` to let it work on a `.NET 4.0 Client Profile` installed machine.

You need to choose whether you really need the Extended version. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/differences-between-microsoft-net-4-0-full-framework-and-client-profile) might help you making your mind up.

My opinion: start building with Client Profile. If there is anything you miss and really need, use and build for Extended.

Comment: ok thanks, will do, So if there is something missing I should quickly know by getting a compile error?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Using `System.Web` is an issue for example. You will notice it directly if you need it for the missing assemblies / methods.

Comment: Ok thanks, One last thing to confirm: Do you mean if they are on client profile and I compile to 4.0 Full version, they won't be able to even run the application ? OR do you mean IF my code is using something that is MISSING in Client Profile version, then they won't be able to run it?  Thank for info

Comment: I thought the difference was embedded in the compiled assembly, so you can't use it if you don't have the right version installed.