# Will Roslyn be part of the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, github, compiler-errors, roslyn

Will Roslyn be part of the .NET framework?
Which version and when?

It is actually available at [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) but it is fairly big and I'm not able to load it in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 without errors.

Comment: it says in the link you provided that *Roslyn is no longer available for Visual Studio 2013.*

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "part of the .NET framework"? What does that have to do with "loading it in Visual Studio"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Roslyn will be part of the .net framework? Which version and
>   when?

Roslyn will be officaly shipping with Visual Studio 2015 RTM, which is currently in [RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx) (which you can download and try). It is [no longer available](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) for VS2013. Generally, there is also a nice web hosted roslyn compiler called [TryRoslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3YBfbLKAA) if you want to try it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if it will be part of client or full portion of the Framework.Net ?

Comment: Client? What do you mean by that? Roslyn will be the compiler from now forward.

Comment: I want to use Roslyn as a script engine in my own program. That way our customer can't script anything they want. In Visual Studio, when we set a project Target Framework, there is "Client Profile" and "Full". I always thought that by default Windows installed a light .net framework on customer machine and if he want the full one, he had to download it explicitly? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759228/differences-between-microsoft-net-4-0-full-framework-and-client-profile

Comment: *Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the Client Profile has been discontinued and only the full redistributable package is available.* That isn't relevant anymore.

Comment: To use Roslyn in your own programs, you'll probably want to add Roslyn as a Nuget reference to your application via the NuGet package manager. If you search by the keyword "Roslyn" you'll get lots of hits. The package you're looking for is "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis".

Comment: TryRoslyn has been renamed SharpLab. Your link still works, but you might want to update the name. See here: https://github.com/ashmind/SharpLab

Answer (score 5):

No, Roslyn is not included in the .Net Framework. Note that, even in .Net Framework 4.6 you'll still find the legacy csc.exe and vbc.exe compilers which we ship for compatibility reasons. They don't support the latest language features and, at release, you'll see that we've changed their banner text to make it clear that these are not the latest versions.

To get the Roslyn-based C# and VB command-line compilers, you have two options:

1. Install Visual Studio 2015 RC. or
2. Install the [MSBuild_tools installer package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46882).

You'll find the Roslyn-based command-line compilers at %ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\bin

Comment: Thanks a lots for the information. I wonder if  I can also take the GitHub version. Wouldn't be more stable (have more bugs fixed)?

Comment: It's not recommended for most purposes but, yes, you could build Roslyn yourself from (a fork of) the GitHub sources. Indeed, if you're interested in scripting C#, this may be your only option at the moment because, as far as I know, we do not include the scripting components in any public Nuget package. Take a look at the [CSharpScripting](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/9bd605388c19a11dae2cb93cd391c07256a609a4/src/Interactive/EditorFeatures/CSharp/CSharpInteractiveEditorFeatures.csproj) project.

Comment: You read my mind. I already made a scripting add-on (script editor) in our project to let our customers modify scripts them self. Thanks a lot for all the precious information. I made it from GitHub source code :-) !