# Is .NET Framework 4 Client profile secure?

Tags: .net, security, .net-4.0

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365918/are-there-any-benefits-of-using-net-framework-4-0-client-profile-nowadays) talks about companies who only support .NET Framework 4 Client profile due to security reasons. But does only allowing use of .NET Framework Client profile increase security? [This answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2788786/463623) talks about that being main case for Client profile. But that was 8 years ago.

I can see two reasons why using .NET Framework 4 Client profile is not as secure as it might seem:

- While surface of .NET API is smaller than full framework, it is still possible to PInvoke any WinAPI method. So there is not much security here.
- Being almost 8 years old, MS might no longer support it, by releasing hotfixes to found security issues. But I was unable to find any information about this.

Is my reasoning above valid? Are there any other reasons why using only .NET Framework 4 Client profile might be more secure than running full and new .NET?

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate what was talked about in the [linked question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/365925/208672):

> ...merely the fact that security updates stopped being issued Jan 2016 should be enough to light a fire under the security conscious.
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/

I don't see how any software that hasn't been patched because it **hasn't been officially supported in over 2 years** could be considered secure.